# Will this snippet in the prestashop template send Google Analytics information using onclick=''

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, prestashop-1.6

in blocksocial.tpl I wanted to send google analytics - social interaction. Would this be the right way to do that? I tried this code on a live site and the clicks were not fired off from the onclick.

`{if isset($facebook_url) && $facebook_url != ''}
            <li class="facebook">
                <a class="_blank" href="{$facebook_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" onclick="ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 'send', '{$facebook_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}');return true;">
                    <span>{l s='Facebook' mod='blocksocial'}</span>
                </a>
           </li>
{/if}`

Answer (score 1):

May be wrap onClick code in to function and use e.preventDefault(); for the link ("a" tag)?

```
{if isset($facebook_url) && $facebook_url != ''}
            <li class="facebook">
                <a class="_blank" href="{$facebook_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" onclick="function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 'send', '{$facebook_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}'); 
        return false; 
        }">
                    <span>{l s='Facebook' mod='blocksocial'}</span>
                </a>
           </li>
{/if}
```

**Update**

I reproduced your code partial. Define the processing function in js code (e.g. in head section):

```
<head>
    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickProcess(url) {
            ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 'send', url); 
            return true; // set false if you don't need the redirect after code execution
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

and then set clickProcess as onClick handler with the url value in arguments:

```
{if isset($facebook_url) && $facebook_url != ''}
            <li class="facebook">
                <a class="_blank" href="{$facebook_url|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" onclick="return clickProcess('{$facebook_url|escape:html:\"UTF-8\"}');">
                    <span>{l s='Facebook' mod='blocksocial'}</span>
                </a>
           </li>
{/if}
```

Comment: I'll try that in a live site right now and see if that works! =)

Comment: Stan, it seems the original did work. it was justing taking time for GA to show it in reporting.  I'm releasing the changes now to prestashop github as an enhancement.